# Distance of Location from a zip (postal) code

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

The Android API has `Location.distanceBetween()`, which accepts two lat/lon values and returns a distance in meters.  Is there a way that I could get this distance with only having a zip (postal) code for one of my points?

Comment: You can use the Google Maps API to get the lat/long for a zip code. It is the geographic center of the zip code IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use Android's [Geocoder API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html). Something like this should work:

```
String locationName = zipCode + ", " + countryName;
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());     
try {
    List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 1);    
    double latitude = address.get(0).getLatitude();
    double longitude = address.get(0).getLongitude();
    Location.distanceBetween(...);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You need to include the country's name because of this: [Get latitude and longitude based on zip using Geocoder class in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281125/get-latitude-and-longitude-based-on-zip-using-geocoder-class-in-android)

Comment: It seems that `Geocoder` can be a little flaky.  It was timing out for me frequently.  [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15236615/1747491) discusses a solution.  I am actually going to just populate a database table instead, since this is very static data.